# D3 - radial stacked bar - how to add background segments

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have based my radial stacked bar/segment chart off of [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3686329aa6e1f5938df8eef12ec353fe). However, I find it difficult to customize in some regards. For example, I want to create a few background colors in each segment. Namely, I want the furthest layer back to be `"#a6a6a6"` gray, then above that I want another slightly narrower segment to be `"#fff"` white. And then, and only then, do I want to dynamically append the radial stacked segments. To recap:

- Top most layer: colored-coded segments
- Middle layer: white (narrower)
- Bottom layer: gray

The result should be color-coded segments on top of a white space background with gray borders separating each segment (as per x-axis). I initially considered using a `stroke` but the taper would not be correct (it would be too thick towards the `innerRadius`).

My attempt is as follows:

```
  graphGroup.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.arc()
          .innerRadius(innerRadius)
          .outerRadius(outerRadius)
          .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.State); })
          .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.State) + x.bandwidth(); })
          .padAngle(0.04)
          .padRadius(innerRadius))
      .attr('fill','#a6a6a6')
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(innerRadius)
            .outerRadius(outerRadius)
            .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.State)+10; })
            .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.State) + x.bandwidth()-10; })
            .padAngle(0.04)
            .padRadius(innerRadius))
        .attr('fill','#fff')
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(function(d) { return y(d[0]); })
            .outerRadius(function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.State); })
            .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.State) + x.bandwidth(); })
            .padAngle(0.04)
            .padRadius(innerRadius));
```

However, it did not work. What happened was for some reason everything appears to be gray. I cannot see any color-coded segments (`z(d.key)`). I'm not sure why this would be because I believe my z-index is correct, I appended the furthest layer (gray) first, and the front-most layer last.

### Question

What is wrong with my background color segment implementation and how should I go about adjusting it?

**Note:** I have simply copied the block above (data and code are the same). I just made the `innerRadius` smaller and deleted the y-axis "ticks" concentric circles.

Comment: Why don't you create a running code that we can play with? Most of people won't have the trouble to write all the necessary code to test their solutions (I mean I won't).

Comment: Also, are you sure you're appending anything with those nested "enter" selections? Use the browser's element inspector to check it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado updated with the full code; it doesn't seem to be working within the snippet, but it works just fine in my development environment.

Comment: It doesn't work in the snippet simply because there is no `"market-share-data.csv"` anywhere. Just use a service like blockbuilder to upload everything, CSV included.